# Update error using ## [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Here is my code:

```
    <cfdump var="#addEnt#" >

    <!-- ADD -->
    <cfquery name="add" datasource="testdatasource" dbtype="OLEDB">
        UPDATE tblrequests
        SET
        lastname='#ucase(form.lastname)#', 
        firstname='#ucase(form.firstname)#', 
        middlei='#ucase(form.middlei)#',
        title='#form.title#', 
        eod='#dateformat(form.eod,'m-d-yyyy')#',
        dutystation='#form.dutystation#', 
        requestsnetwork=<cfif parameterexists(form.requestsnetwork)>1<cfelse>0</cfif>, 
        affiliation='#form.affiliation#',
        commentssupvreq='#form.commentssupvreq#', 
        requestdelete=<cfif form.requestdelete IS NOT ''>'#dateformat(form.requestdelete,'m-d-yyyy')#',<cfelse>Null,</cfif>
        commentssupvdelete='#form.commentssupvdelete#',
        commentssupvedit='#form.commentssupvedit#',
        dateemailrequested=<cfif form.dateemailrequested IS NOT ''>'#dateformat(form.dateemailrequested,'m-d-yyyy')#',<cfelse>Null,</cfif>
        commentsit='#form.commentsit#',
        bgcomplete=<cfif form.bgcomplete IS NOT ''>'#dateformat(form.bgcomplete,'m-d-yyyy')#',<cfelse>Null,</cfif>
        dategroupscreated=<cfif form.dategroupscreated IS NOT ''>'#dateformat(form.dategroupscreated,'m-d-yyyy')#',<cfelse>Null,</cfif>
        WHERE recnumber = #addEnt#      
    </cfquery>
```

When I submit the form I get an error:

> Error Executing Database Query.     [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC
>   Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

My cfdump displays the correct `addent` number from sql, but using #addEnt# in the sql statement is not working. Other pages in my applications ## for SQL queries and they work fine.

Comment: You have a comma with your last SET statement. Also you should really look into using `cfqueryparam` to reduce your risk of SQL injection. Right now your query is very vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Ah! Had to delete both commas! Thanks!

Comment: Without the query parameters, your query will crash when someone named O'Hara submits the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line in your set statements has a comma at the end, which is where the SQL will be complaining

Comment: Had to delete both ,  Thanks!

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 100.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: @DanBracuk anytime you come to north west montana let me know.

Answer (score 4):

(Too long for comments)

As suggested in the comments, there are several improvements you could make to the query: one of the biggest, being the addition of [cfqueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html). It provides several advantages, such as:

- CFQueryparam, or [bind variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), help improve performance by encouraging databases to reuse query execution plans, rather than generating a new one each time (which is a costly operation).
- Bind variables also prevent the *execution* of client supplied values as SQL commands, which has the happy side effect of preventing common forms of [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
- CF's implementation of bind variables also provides an extra layer of validation, by type checking input values, *before* the query is ever executed. So when invalid parameters are detected, it saves a wasted trip to the database.

A few other tips for improving the query

- Although it makes no syntactical difference, consider placing commas at the beginning of each line, rather than at the end. This makes it easier to spot extra or missing commas:

  ```
  UPDATE SomeTable
  SET    ColumnA   = 'xxxx'
         , ColumnB = 'yyyy'
         , ColumnC = 'zzzzz'
         , ColumnD = 'xxxx'
         , ColumnE = 'yyyy'
  WHERE ....
  ```
- It looks like your query is populating several datetime columns. When working with datetime columns, it best to use date *objects*, not strings. Date strings are ambiguous, and can be interpreted differently than you might expect, depending on the database or settings. To insert a date only, use `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" ...>`, for both date *and* time use `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" ...>`. Obviously, always validate the date strings first.
- Consider using cfqueryparam's `null` attribute. It can be quite handy when inserting null values conditionally. (See example below)
- As an aside, [ParameterExists](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parameterexists.html) was deprecated a while ago and replaced with [IsDefined](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbd.html), or preferably [StructKeyExists](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structkeyexists.html). In this case, another alternative to a CFIF is to declare a default with [cfparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfparam.html), so the form field in question always exists.

Putting it all together, your final query might look something like this. I guessed about the column data types, so adjust as needed.

```
UPDATE tblrequests
SET    lastname             = <cfqueryparam value="#ucase(form.lastname)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      , firstname           = <cfqueryparam value="#ucase(form.firstname)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  middlei            = <cfqueryparam value="#ucase(form.middlei)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  title              = <cfqueryparam value="#form.title#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  eod                = <cfqueryparam value="#form.eod#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
      ,  dutystation        = <cfqueryparam value="#form.dutyStation#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  requestsnetwork    = <cfqueryparam value="#form.requestsNetwork#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit">
      ,  affiliation        = <cfqueryparam value="#form.affiliation#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  commentssupvreq    = <cfqueryparam value="#form.commentsSupvReq#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  requestdelete      = <cfqueryparam value="#form.requestDelete#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" null="#not isDate(form.requestDelete)#">
      ,  commentssupvdelete = <cfqueryparam value="#form.commentssupvdelete#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  commentssupvedit   = <cfqueryparam value="#form.commentssupvedit#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  dateemailrequested = <cfqueryparam value="#form.dateEmailRequested#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" null="#not isDate(form.dateEmailRequested)#">
      ,  commentsit         = <cfqueryparam value="#form.commentsit#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
      ,  bgcomplete         = <cfqueryparam value="#form.bgComplete#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" null="#not isDate(form.bgComplete)#">
      ,  dategroupscreated  = <cfqueryparam value="#form.dateGroupsCreated#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" null="#not isDate(form.dateGroupsCreated)#">
WHERE recnumber = <cfqueryparam value="#addEnt#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
```

Comment: Yes! This. All this. Very nicely written.